Facing this error while building a component name data storage backup redis
i tried building aws-sdk-cpp multiple times but still facing issue.
I am using openssl 3.0.2 and curl 7.88 along with ubuntu 20.04.
the errors are related to aws-sdk-cpp and openssl. i need the solutions at the earliest. Does anyone have any idea how to resole this then please do help.
error
